# Python - index in enumerate

Tags: python

I am just starting to learn Python. At what index value in python does a `for` loop start from?

For example, if I have a text file with 390 lines, and I iterate:

`for i, word in enumerate(f)`

Does the value of the index start from `0` or from `1`? 
Also, if I want to print out every 30th line in the file, then will I have to iterate like this?

```
if i+1 in [30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,360,390]:
    print i
    ...
```

Comment: These things are best learned by trying.

Comment: I did try it. But, it made no sense for a new programmer like me. Python is VERY different from C/CUDA and I'm learning that slowly :)

Answer (score 6):

when you are using for loop with a list. It includes all the elements in the list starting from the zero'th:
if `f=['x','y','z']`

```
for i, word in enumerate(f):
    print i, word
```

would output:

```
0 x
1 y
2 z
```

for printing every 30th line. You can use

```
for i in range(0,390,30):
```

which would output: 0, 30 ,60 90, ...

Answer (score 3):

For your first question: the index starts at `0`, as is generally the case in Python. (Of course, this would have been very easy to try for yourself and see).

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for i, word in enumerate(x):
    print i, word


0 a
1 b
2 c
```

For your second question: a much better way to handle printing every 30th line is to use the mod operator `%`:

```
if i+1 % 30 == 0:
    print i
    # ...
```

This is slightly better than testing for membership in `range` since you don't have to worry about edge effects (i.e. since `range` gives a half-open interval that is open on the right end).

Answer (score 1):

By default, enumerate() starts at 0.  If you want to start at one, pass it a second parameter at which you want to start:

```
for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
    print i, line
```

If you want to print every 30th line, here is an easy way to do it.

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if (i+1) % 30 == 0:
        print line
```

If you don't know the '%' (mod) operator, 'i % 30 == 0' is like asking "is the remainder zero after dividing i by 30?"

Answer (score 0):

From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> Python’s **`for`** statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.

So it will iterate in the specified range. To get the range `[30, 60, ... 390]`. You can try using the built-in function `range` or `xrange`(which yields element by element):

```
for i in range(30, 390 + 1, 30):  # range(start, end, step)
    print i
```

Answering the question about wheter the *index* starts from `0` or `1`, try printing `tuple(enumerate(['a','b','c']))`. It looks like:

```
print tuple(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']))
>>> ((0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'))
```

so when you do

```
for i, element in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
```

`i` will iterate over `0, 1, 2` and `element` over `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example above:

If you open your python shell and type this:

```
for i, word in enumerate(f):
   print i, word
```

you see that the output will be:

```
0 30
1 60
2 90
3 120
4 150
5 180
6 210
7 240
8 270
9 300
10 330
11 360
12 390
```

So, to answer your question, it starts from index 0.
As for the second question, you can use readlines() method and print on every 30th iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Python has its own std lib to do that: using [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("txt.txt"):
    if fileinput.lineno() % 30 == 0:
        print fileinput.lineno(), line,
```

BTW if you are using enumerate, then the index start from 0, so when you test it you should test `(n + 1) % 30 == 0`  # where n is the current index